# Does a path inherit settings from a root path location element when a another location element exists?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have my web.config in an ASP app applying most settings to the root path e.g.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  ...
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login" name="APP" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</location>
```

I then allow anonymous access to the "api" path as follows.

```
<location path="api" inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Will the other settings applied in the root path location element apply to the "api" path?

I've had some strange behaviour in production and found adding the `<system.webServer>` configuration above fixed it. This wasn't needed before moving the bulk of the configuration into the root path location element.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the `api` path is in a child application.

If the `api` path is *not* in a child application, yes, the other settings applied to the root location *will* apply to it.

If the `api` path *is* in a child application, no, the other settings applied to the root location will *not* apply to it - per `inheritInChildApplications="false"`.

I confirmed this with a web root and an `api` subfolder in a VS 2013 web application:

1. Run in IIS Express as-is (i.e. `api` not a child application).
2. Run in IIS with the root as an application and `api` as a child application.

See [MSDN's documentation for the `location` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - specifically its `inheritInChildApplications` attribute - for more information.

Comment: These are both in the same app so inheritInChildApplications shouldnt affect this case. I think you're right but I can't understand why I need to copy part of the root path. Also I've read that the order of the location is important however if I place the "api" before or after the "." it makes no difference even in regards to the authorization.

Comment: I've done some more testing and while it looks like the system.web settings are being inherited the system.webServer settings are not. I've found other webServer settings such as validateIntegratedModeConfiguration are not applying to the other locations.